# how to use the linear regression of MLlib of apache spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm new to the apache spark, and from the document of MLlib, i found a example of scala, but i really don't know scala, is anyone knows a example in java? thanks! the example code is

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint

// Load and parse the data
val data = sc.textFile("mllib/data/ridge-data/lpsa.data")
val parsedData = data.map { line =>
  val parts = line.split(',')
  LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, parts(1).split(' ').map(x => x.toDouble).toArray)
}

// Building the model
val numIterations = 20
val model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(parsedData, numIterations)

// Evaluate model on training examples and compute training error
val valuesAndPreds = parsedData.map { point =>
  val prediction = model.predict(point.features)
  (point.label, prediction)
}
val MSE = valuesAndPreds.map{ case(v, p) => math.pow((v - p), 2)}.reduce(_ +     _)/valuesAndPreds.count
println("training Mean Squared Error = " + MSE)
```

from the document of [MLlib](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-guide.html)
thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As indicated in the documentation :

> All of MLlib’s methods use Java-friendly types, so you can import and
>   call them there the same way you do in Scala. The only caveat is that
>   the methods take Scala RDD objects, while the Spark Java API uses a
>   separate JavaRDD class. You can convert a Java RDD to a Scala one by
>   calling .rdd() on your JavaRDD object.

This is not easy, since you still have to reproduce the scala code in java, but it works (at least in this case).

Having said that, here is a java implementation :

```
public void linReg() {
    String master = "local";
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("csvParser").setMaster(
            master);
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile("mllib/data/ridge-data/lpsa.data");
    JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> parseddata = data
            .map(new Function<String, LabeledPoint>() {
            // I see no ways of just using a lambda, hence more verbosity than with scala
                @Override
                public LabeledPoint call(String line) throws Exception {
                    String[] parts = line.split(",");
                    String[] pointsStr = parts[1].split(" ");
                    double[] points = new double[pointsStr.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < pointsStr.length; i++)
                        points[i] = Double.valueOf(pointsStr[i]);
                    return new LabeledPoint(Double.valueOf(parts[0]),
                            Vectors.dense(points));
                }
            });

    // Building the model
    int numIterations = 20;
    LinearRegressionModel model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(
    parseddata.rdd(), numIterations); // notice the .rdd()

    // Evaluate model on training examples and compute training error
    JavaRDD<Tuple2<Double, Double>> valuesAndPred = parseddata
            .map(point -> new Tuple2<Double, Double>(point.label(), model
                    .predict(point.features())));
    // important point here is the Tuple2 explicit creation.

    double MSE = valuesAndPred.mapToDouble(
            tuple -> Math.pow(tuple._1 - tuple._2, 2)).mean();
    // you can compute the mean with this function, which is much easier
    System.out.println("training Mean Squared Error = "
            + String.valueOf(MSE));
}
```

It is far from being perfect, but I hope it will make you understand better how to use scala examples on Mllib documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
package org.apache.spark.examples;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Logistic regression based classification.
 *
 * This is an example implementation for learning how to use Spark. For more conventional use,
 * please refer to either org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithSGD or
 * org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS based on your needs.
 */
public final class JavaHdfsLR {

  private static final int D = 10;   // Number of dimensions
  private static final Random rand = new Random(42);

  static void showWarning() {
    String warning = "WARN: This is a naive implementation of Logistic Regression " +
            "and is given as an example!\n" +
            "Please use either org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithSGD " +
            "or org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS " +
            "for more conventional use.";
    System.err.println(warning);
  }

  static class DataPoint implements Serializable {
    DataPoint(double[] x, double y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }

    double[] x;
    double y;
  }

  static class ParsePoint implements Function<String, DataPoint> {
    private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");

    @Override
    public DataPoint call(String line) {
      String[] tok = SPACE.split(line);
      double y = Double.parseDouble(tok[0]);
      double[] x = new double[D];
      for (int i = 0; i < D; i++) {
        x[i] = Double.parseDouble(tok[i + 1]);
      }
      return new DataPoint(x, y);
    }
  }

  static class VectorSum implements Function2<double[], double[], double[]> {
    @Override
    public double[] call(double[] a, double[] b) {
      double[] result = new double[D];
      for (int j = 0; j < D; j++) {
        result[j] = a[j] + b[j];
      }
      return result;
    }
  }

  static class ComputeGradient implements Function<DataPoint, double[]> {
    private final double[] weights;

    ComputeGradient(double[] weights) {
      this.weights = weights;
    }

    @Override
    public double[] call(DataPoint p) {
      double[] gradient = new double[D];
      for (int i = 0; i < D; i++) {
        double dot = dot(weights, p.x);
        gradient[i] = (1 / (1 + Math.exp(-p.y * dot)) - 1) * p.y * p.x[i];
      }
      return gradient;
    }
  }

  public static double dot(double[] a, double[] b) {
    double x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < D; i++) {
      x += a[i] * b[i];
    }
    return x;
  }

  public static void printWeights(double[] a) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (args.length < 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: JavaHdfsLR <file> <iters>");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    showWarning();

    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaHdfsLR");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile(args[0]);
    JavaRDD<DataPoint> points = lines.map(new ParsePoint()).cache();
    int ITERATIONS = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    // Initialize w to a random value
    double[] w = new double[D];
    for (int i = 0; i < D; i++) {
      w[i] = 2 * rand.nextDouble() - 1;
    }

    System.out.print("Initial w: ");
    printWeights(w);

    for (int i = 1; i <= ITERATIONS; i++) {
      System.out.println("On iteration " + i);

      double[] gradient = points.map(
        new ComputeGradient(w)
      ).reduce(new VectorSum());

      for (int j = 0; j < D; j++) {
        w[j] -= gradient[j];
      }

    }

    System.out.print("Final w: ");
    printWeights(w);
    sc.stop();
  }
}
```