# How to do regression of 2 dimensions (x,y) determines z in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a data set of x,y values which determine z, how can I used Apache Spark to do regression to find a fit (find the function) from x,y to z? I cannot find any example, can someone point to an example or help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23942043/how-to-use-the-linear-regression-of-mllib-of-apache-spark

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#regression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of examples. However you have to keep in mind the library you want to use, i.e. if the data is a `DataFrame` you might want to use [ml](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html), but if the data comes in an `RDD` structure then you might prefer [mllib](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html) instead.

e.g. for `mllib` and in `python`:

```py
# 1. import the required libraries.
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint, LinearRegressionWithSGD
import numpy as np

# 2. read your data or create it. 
trainingData = sc.parallelize([(23.0, [-1.0, 2.0]), (13.0, [0.5, 2.0]),
                               (15.0, [-2.0, 1.0]), (10.0, [1.0, 0.4])])

# 3. fit your model.
lrModel = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(trainingData)

# 4. make predictions.
myPrediction = lrModel.predict(np.array([1.0, -2.0]))
```

Note: I really recommend you to audit two courses of edx (both use Apache Spark): [Introduction to Big Data](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-big-data-apache-spark-uc-berkeleyx-cs100-1x), and [Scalable Machine Learning](https://www.edx.org/course/scalable-machine-learning-uc-berkeleyx-cs190-1x)